# How to untar multiple tar.gz file at a time in r

Tags: r

I have 11 *.tar.gz file in the directory. I tried this

```
untar("./Extract_data/AQS.tar.gz", exdir = "./Extract_data")
```

For each file I have to write this. Is there any way I can `untar` all the files tar.gz in a directory with one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
file_list<- list.files(  , pattern = "*.tar.gz", full.names = TRUE)
library(plyr)
ldply(.data = file_list, .fun = untar, exdir = "./untar_data")
```